# How is `return <boolean exp> || <Object exp>` a valid return statement for a method that returns an Object?

Tags: java, return-type, boolean-expression, short-circuiting

I was reading a book, and saw this code:

```
public Animal getWinner(List<Animal> animals) {
    return animals == null || animals.size() == 0 ? null : animals.get(0);
}
```

The latter expression is fine as it returns an Animal or null. The former expression is puzzling though, as it's just a boolean expression.

I made a test class and called `getWinner(null)`. It returned `null`. As far as I know, `animals == null` would be true, the expression would short-circuit, and I expect the method to return `true` instead of `null`.

How does this line compile, and even work as expected?

Comment: Wow, a member for 8 years and _now_ you ask a question. You really lurk in the shadows :-)

Comment: Absolutely! See you in 2026! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with [operator precedence](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) in Java and which operator - the boolean or the ternary, will be executed first.

The ternary has lower precedence, so the `or` will be evaluated first, meaning it would look like this with parenthesis:

```
return (animals == null || animals.size() == 0) ? null : animals.get(0);
```

So the result of the entire line is either to `return null` or `return animals.get(0)`.

Comment: When in doubt: add parenthesis. The next programmer will thank you :D